# How to create a custom field that gets URL counts from LinkedIn on external articles?

Tags: entities, social-network

My site has a content type named News, which receives news from external RSS feed. Therefore, content type News has the following fields:

- Title = article title (i.e. Hapag-Lloyd orders five container ships for more Panama Canal trade)
- URL = external url field (i.e. http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/04/20/hapaglloyd-ships-idUSL5N0XH3XQ20150420)
- Source = external website source (i.e.Reuters)

I would like to create 3 fields in the content type that shows count of article has been shared on LinkedIn in using the following function:

```
http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/04/20/hapaglloyd-ships-idUSL5N0XH3XQ20150420&format=json
```

Return

```
{"count":28,"fCnt":"28","fCntPlusOne":"29","url":"http:\/\/www.reuters.com\/article\/2015\/04\/20\/hapaglloyd-ships-idUSL5N0XH3XQ20150420"}
```

Fields to be displayed:

- count (i.e. 28)
- fCnt (i.e. 28)
- fCntPlusOne (i.e 29)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a custom module for this with specific fields for twitter an linkedin. The module will call the JSON function every time the node is saved.

Additionally, a cron has been set up to be run every 5 minutes and re-save the nodes which make the node to be updated with the right count.